# PowerShell Get-Appx -AllUsers fails with "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am trying to list all Appx packages on a domestic Win 10 laptop with Powershell (with a view to completely removing many of them to create space in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps) but when I try to list them from a Powershell Admin session I get the message

"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

and no apps are listed.

Comment: What is the command used? Are you in a domain?

Comment: Yes, machine is in domain alekatest.local. Command is Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers

Comment: Is this all happening on one computer or over the network?

Comment: All on one domestic machine.

Comment: I never seen this in PowerShell, but i've seen it when trying to login with a domain user. Normally leaving the domain and re-joining the domain works.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the Microsoft Store components are corrupted.

To reset the Microsoft Store, try these in order:

- Run `WSReset.exe`
- Run PowerShell as Administrator and enter the following command:

  ```
    Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
  ```

Comment: No effect - not the problem

Comment: THe problem was that the domain controller was not accessible - I'd been running with cached credentials. I left the domain, joined a Workgroup and now Get-AppxPackage works fine.

Comment: So this wasn't happening only on on one domestic machine. Congrats on solving the problem.

Comment: I did have to copy my profile from the domain account and lost a few default program assignments but this wasn't hard to rectify. Some file and folder ownerships became inaccessible as well but again not hard to fix

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a UserName instead AllUsers

```
$user=whoami
Get-AppXPackage -User $user | Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```